# Is there a way to only load images when display is not none?

Tags: javascript, html, image, load

Pretty simple question:

Can I force a browser to not download any images or other resources if they are display:none, but then, of course download when display is switched to inline?

Here is the concept: A lecture presentation with many slides as images all set to display:none by default then changed to display:inline when the video reaches a certain time index. The browser still tries to load all of the images even though they are not displayed which might cause a hang on the video or elements that should load after the slide images.

I have a series of these:

```
<figure class="lectureNotCurrent" data-start="0" data-end="259">
<a href="img1_large.JPG" target="_blank">
<img src="img1_large.JPG" class="lectureSlidesImg" /></a></figure>
```

EDIT - SHOULD WORK?

```
<img data-src=/path/to/img.png src="">

//js
loadNextImages() {
   document.querySelectorAll("#slidesContainer footer").map(function () {
       this.getElementsByTagName('img').src = this.getElementsByTagName('img').dataset.src;
       delete this.dataset.src;
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you using/can you use JavaScript in any way?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, that is fine and I am comfortable with js

Comment: I think browser already do it automagically. At least in Opera on slow connections you can "feel" that images are first loaded, when the get visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

HTML

```
<figure class="lectureNotCurrent" data-start="0" data-end="259">
<a href="img1_large.JPG" target="_blank">
<img data-src="img1_large.JPG" src="" class="lectureSlidesImg" /></a></figure>
```

In the function that runs the timings for the slides I added the variable:

```
var imgNames = document.getElementsByClassName('lectureSlidesImg');
```

I then added this statement in the section of code (a 'for' loop) that applies display:inline to the figure tags at the correct moments according to the video's current time.

```
imgNames[i].src = imgNames[i].getAttribute('data-src');
```

So in addition to displaying the figure tag in question it will also take the data-src value for the image in question and insert it in the src attribute. The image then loads.

There is a lot of power behind the data-* custom attributes. Glad I learned about those.

One would think, however, that display:none should prevent loading the content unless the display is changed.

Answer (score 5):

Update your html so that the hidden images don't have `src` (or have a one transparent pixel file as the source, for example) and use `data-src` and change the `src` when it's displayed:

```
<img data-src=/path/to/img.png src="">

//js
loadNextImages() {
    document.querySelectorAll("#container img").map(function () {
        this.src = this.dataset.src;
        delete this.dataset.src;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok. I see how this would work. Is data-src a real attribute or would I have to create that first?

Comment: @fredsbend http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: See my edit with the actual code I am using. The code for the timings is in the data-* for figure tags. How might I apply this function without change that structure? If necessary I can change the structure, but I would rather not.

Comment: @fredsbend You have to because you have to remove the `src` attribute from the `<img>`.  If you don't, the image will be downloaded and there's no way around that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean except that and adding the data-src attribute. How would the javascript know when to run the function? Where would I put it? I only want an image to load if the video is within the time set in the data-* figure tags.

Comment: Don't you have some JS that checks data-start/data-end values at some point?

Comment: Yes, I thought in that function but using 'this' means it will apply src="img.png" to the figure tag, right?

Comment: @fredsbend correct, but finding the child `<img>` should be trivial `this.getElementsByTagName('img')`

Comment: Close, but `getElementsByTagName` returns a list.  If there will only ever be one image, you can just use `[0]`, but if there will be more than one you have to iterate.  Don't forget to change the `delete` statement too (although you probably don't even need it).

Comment: I came up with something simpler, however, I upped your answer because it set me on the right track.